# Check if ANYYY values exists in table MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I am making a java Program about User Account Creating and i want to check if there was any username of password before in table.

```
String kullanici_adi = KullaniciAdi.getText();
       String sifre = Sifre.getText();
       String query = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS BUTTERFLYFLY";
       Statement SQL=null;
       Statement SQLD=null;
       String yol="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
       String yol2="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/butterflyfly";
        try {
            Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection(yol, "root", "");
            SQL = con.createStatement();
            SQL.close();
            con.close();
            Connection cond=DriverManager.getConnection(yol2, "root", "");
            Main m=new Main();
            String x=m.oturum_kurulumu;
            SQLD= cond.createStatement();
            SQLD.executeUpdate(x);


            /* If there is a username or password in table pass this
            PreparedStatement stmt = cond.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Oturum (Kullanici_Adi, Sifre)\n" +
"VALUES (?, ?);");
            stmt.setString(1, kullanici_adi);
            stmt.setString(2, sifre);
            stmt.executeUpdate();

*/
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Bir hata olustu");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

I want to dedect value on table, i researched and i just found check spesific value like
*SELECT  numR  FROM  `reference` WHERE  numR =  "x"*

But i want to check just if there is a any value on table pass the code

Answer (score 0):

When you create a unique key on `Kullanici_Adi` with:

```
ALTER TABLE Oturum ADD UNIQUE (Kullanici_Adi);
```

To replace existing password:

```
INSERT INTO Oturum VALUES (%s, %s)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Sifre=%s
```

[ref](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) for INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.

If you want to keep existing values:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO Oturum VALUES (%s, %s)
```

[ref](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html) for INSERT IGNORE.

The rows affected in both statements will indicate if there was an existing row.

The problem with a "check" is its subject to race conditions, another web query could run between the check and whatever action you choose to take on the table. So when doing database code, think about race conditions and do those atomicity (or in a transaction).

Comment: hmm How can i check like if there is a any value on table, make variable x=1?

Comment: what do you want on doing with the check on `x`? What are the consequences if the data changes before you do what you where going to do with `x`?